Join independent queries together based on common column
I have the below query where I am computing an average based on a dyamic date range given (i.e 10-01-2024 - 10-28-2024). This is column SUM(ROUND(QTY_AVG.AVERAGE,2)) DATE_RANGE_AVERAGE shown below.
I have another subquery I am using to join to that calculates a Yearly average based on a hard-coded date range and I am joining back to the main query based on ITEM_ID (QTY_AVG_YEAR.ITEM_ID = rsl.ITEM_ID) so that I can show the Yearly average as a column next to the dynamic average column. The issue is that the join aliased as 'QTY_AVG_YEAR' is skewing the DATE_RANGE_AVERAGE column because I believe it's fetching in more rows for the entire year period.
How can I essentially have two queries that have independent results that aren't influenced by one another, but are displayed together in the results based on the Item ID?
I essentially want to query one dataset to get the average from the dynamic range, and another query for the average for the year (independently so as not to affect what rows join), and then output in the same row based on ITEM_ID as an additional column.
I hope that makes sense.
select         
     esib.item_number inv_item_id, --:INV_ITEM_ID, 
       pla.item_description descr254_mixed

,SUM(ROUND(QTY_AVG.AVERAGE,2)) DATE_RANGE_AVERAGE
--,SUM(ROUND(QTY_AVG_YEAR.AVERAGE_YEAR,2)) YEAR_AVERAGE

  from po_headers_all pha,
       po_lines_all pla,
       po_line_locations_all plla,
       po_distributions_all pda,
       rcv_shipment_headers rsh,
       rcv_shipment_lines rsl,
       rcv_transactions rt,
      egp_system_items_b esib,
       inv_org_parameters iop,
       GL_CODE_COMBINATIONS GCC,
     HR_ALL_ORGANIZATION_UNITS_F_VL HR,
    INV_UOM_CONVERSIONS INTRACONV                   
       
     , (SELECT SUM(LN.QUANTITY_RECEIVED)/(:P_TO_DATE - :P_FROM_DATE) AVERAGE, SHIPMENT_HEADER_ID, shipment_line_id
       FROM rcv_shipment_lines LN
       WHERE LN.CREATION_DATE >= :P_FROM_DATE
         AND LN.CREATION_DATE <= :P_TO_DATE
       GROUP BY SHIPMENT_HEADER_ID, shipment_line_id ) QTY_AVG      
             
     , (SELECT SUM(LN.QUANTITY_RECEIVED)/365 AVERAGE_YEAR, SHIPMENT_HEADER_ID, shipment_line_id, ITEM_ID
       FROM rcv_shipment_lines LN
       WHERE TO_CHAR(LN.CREATION_DATE, 'yyyy-mm-dd') >= '2023-10-23'
         AND TO_CHAR(LN.CREATION_DATE, 'yyyy-mm-dd') <= '2024-09-30'
          --AND LN.ITEM_ID = :INV_ITEM_ID    --rsl.ITEM_ID
          --AND ITEM_ID =100000030622932
       GROUP BY SHIPMENT_HEADER_ID, shipment_line_id, ITEM_ID ) QTY_AVG_YEAR  

       
WHERE pha.po_header_id = pla.po_header_id
   and pla.po_line_id = plla.po_line_id
   and plla.line_location_id = pda.line_location_id
   and rt.po_header_id = pha.po_header_id
   AND transaction_type = 'RECEIVE'
   AND GCC.CODE_COMBINATION_ID = PDA.CODE_COMBINATION_ID    
AND pha.SEGMENT1 = NVL(:P_PO_ID, pha.SEGMENT1)   
AND HR.organization_id = rt.ORGANIZATION_ID                                                      
AND INTRACONV.UOM_CODE(+) = CASE WHEN esib.UNIT_OF_ISSUE IS NOT NULL THEN esib.UNIT_OF_ISSUE ELSE rsl.UOM_CODE END
AND INTRACONV.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID(+)  = esib.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID 

      AND QTY_AVG.SHIPMENT_HEADER_ID = rsl.SHIPMENT_HEADER_ID
      AND QTY_AVG.shipment_line_id = rsl.shipment_line_id      
      
  AND QTY_AVG_YEAR.ITEM_ID = rsl.ITEM_ID          
  
  AND YEAR_AVERAGE.ITEM_ID(+) = rsl.ITEM_ID

AND rt.transaction_date BETWEEN

to_date(nvl( to_char(:P_FROM_DATE,'yyyy-mm-dd') , to_char(sysdate - 30, 'YYYY-MM-DD')) ||' 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:Mi:SS')

 AND 

to_date(nvl( to_char(:P_TO_DATE,'yyyy-mm-dd') , to_char(sysdate - 1 , 'YYYY-MM-DD')) ||' 23:59:59', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:Mi:SS')
 
 AND esib.item_number IN ('111090',
               '112252',
               '14438',
               '20',
               '112399',
               '110844',
               '221',
               '85866',
               '112304',
               '219',
               '112078' )

GROUP BY 
        esib.item_number , 
        pla.item_description  

Correct results with only the dynamic date range column:
INV_ITEM_ID  DESCR254_MIXED               DATE_RANGE_AVERAGE
------------------------------------------------------------
219          SALINE, 1000CC IRRIGATION    5.37
221          SALINE, 3000 CC IRRIGATION   5.36
14438        SOLN, SOD CHLOR .9% 250CC    1.64
112252       SOLUTION INTRAVENOUS SODIUM  2.41
112304       SOL IRRIG NACL 0.9% USP      3.56
       

Incorrect results with dynamic date range and year average columns:
INV_ITEM_ID    DESCR254_MIXED               DATE_RANGE_AVERAGE  YEAR_AVERAGE
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
219            SALINE, 1000CC IRRIGATION    1154.55             72.39
221            SALINE, 3000 CC IRRIGATION   766.48              105.1
14438          SOLN, SOD CHLOR .9% 250CC    354.24              30.25
112252         SOLUTION INTRAVENOUS SODIUM  245.82              11.52
112304         SOL IRRIG NACL 0.9% USP      202.92              7.6


Instead of joins you may use ROLLUP clause, they may work easier. See https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/rollup-cube-grouping-functions-and-grouping-sets#rollup

Some minor issues: learn modern (well, it exists for more than 20 years) ANSI join syntax instead of ancient Oracle join syntax. Compare DATE values with DATE instead of converting them forth and back to strings. Numeric values should be stored and compared with NUMBER values.

I suspect you actually want to join QTY_AVG_YEAR on shipment_header_id and shipment_line_id as well. Try adding your join columns (item_id, shipment_header_id, shipment_line_id) to your SELECTed columns to see why your join isn't working as expected.

This is hard to understand since there are no sample data at all and the sql provided is just unreadable, but if your question is how to get from the same source data and in the same row the date range dayly average and the year's dayly average  then one option is to use conditional aggregation with Case expressions.  Something like below:
--      S a m p l e    D a t a :
Create Table rcv_shipment_lines ( SHIPMENT_HEADER_ID Number(6), 
                                  SHIPMENT_LINE_ID Number(6), 
                                  ITEM_ID Number(6),
                                  QUANTITY_RECEIVED Number(12,3), 
                                  CREATION_DATE Date 
                                );
Insert Into rcv_shipment_lines
  Select   1, 11, 221, 1000, DATE '2024-01-01'  From Dual Union All 
  Select   1, 11, 221, 1500, DATE '2024-02-01'  From Dual Union All 
  Select   1, 12, 221, 2000, DATE '2024-04-01'  From Dual Union All 
  Select   1, 12, 221, 2500, DATE '2024-05-01'  From Dual Union All 
  Select   2, 13, 219, 7000, DATE '2024-04-01'  From Dual Union All 
  Select   2, 14, 219, 1500, DATE '2024-05-01'  From Dual Union All 
  Select   3, 33, 219, 1000, DATE '2024-08-01'  From Dual Union All 
  Select   3, 44, 219, 6500, DATE '2024-09-01'  From Dual;

... with the above simplified data you can get both averages ...
--      S Q L : 
Select      r.ITEM_ID, 'Some mixed descriptions for item id ' || r.item_id  "DESCR254_MIXED", 
            ROUND( Sum( Case When r.CREATION_DATE Between DATE '2024-03-28' And DATE '2024-05-10' 
                            Then QUANTITY_RECEIVED
                        Else 0 
                        End ) /  ( DATE '2024-05-10' - DATE '2024-03-28' ), 2 ) "DATE_RANGE_AVERAGE", 
            ROUND( Sum( Case When EXTRACT(Year From r.CREATION_DATE) = EXTRACT(Year From DATE '2024-05-10') 
                             Then QUANTITY_RECEIVED
                        Else 0
                        End ) / 365, 2 ) "YEAR_AVERAGE"
From        rcv_shipment_lines r
Group By    r.ITEM_ID
Order By    r.ITEM_ID

R e s u l t :



ITEM_ID
DESCR254_MIXED
DATE_RANGE_AVERAGE
YEAR_AVERAGE




219
Some mixed descriptions for item id 219
197.67
43.84


221
Some mixed descriptions for item id 221
104.65
19.18



fiddle
NOTE:
The DATEs used as values and/or conditions within Case expressions should be replaced with your bind variables :P_FROM_DATE and :P_TO_DATE ...
